# Geometry question : Find angle z

Tags: geometry

Here is a right angle joined together in such a way that the hypotenuse of the upper right triangle is equal to the side of the lower triangle.

[image]

I tried to draw a fit to scale diagram but I couldn't get the dimensions right.
Then I assumed this diagram to be cyclic and applied the circle property and solved it using similar triangles.[Here is my working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tcpc0.jpg)
is it right to assume this triangle to be cyclic or is there any other way to solve this?.
I'm a high school student so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Every triangle is cyclic. If you meant "quadrilateral ABCD is cyclic", then that is not a valid assumption.

Comment: Your working seems correct.

Comment: yes,that is what i meant i appologize.

Comment: @QuarterLemon Can you justify the assumption that "quadrilateral ABCD is cyclic"?  With that assumption, I agree that the rest of the working seems correct.

Comment: It is correct @CalvinLin assuming the bottom most angle is right.

Comment: You're right.  However,  without that assumption, the angle $z$ could take an infinite number of values.

Comment: @QuarterLemon I disagree. There is a unique $z$ that will result in the configuration. EG If $z$ is too large  (say $90^\circ$), then clearly $AC$ will not be bisected by $BD$.

Comment: HINT. $z=30°$...

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Not quite sure how that is a hint. How does that guide OP on what to do after that? It might be better to suggest a construction that they could use, or even stating if the approach is trig / coordinate geom / etc.

Comment: @CalvinLin They can check if this angle is correct, for instance.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca How does checking that this one angle is correct imply that there must only be 1 solution? Why can't there be "an infinite number of values" like Quarter Lemon is claiming?   (FWIW I agree that the answer is $ z = 30 ^\circ$.)

Comment: @CalvinLin I think that just to check that angle is correct one is led to understand some things about the figure and devise some possible proof.

Comment: Thanks guys ! I just solved it.

Answer (score 2):

The two triangles $ABC$ and $DEC$ are similar.
[image]

Comment: how are the two triangles $ABC$ and $DEC$ are similar even if $CB=CD$?

Comment: Because they have the same angle at point C. And they both have a right angle. So the angle Z at point A is equal to the angle at D.